# Laravel Session package (outside laravel ) session data not sticking across routes

Tags: session, laravel

Laravel Session package (outside laravel) session data not sticking across routes

index.php code:

```
$manager = new StartSession($app['session']); 
$response = $manager->handle(
  $app['request'],
  function(Illuminate\Http\Request $request){   
    return  Route::dispatchToRoute($request); 
  }
);
$manager->terminate();
$response->send();
```

route file:

```
Route::get('auth', function() {
  Session::put('Maxhunter', 'this is my name');
  dd(Session::all()); // output  
                      // array:2 [▼ "_token" => "7UM4Q61zR3WNGPIMFQ8Rmo7dqtdJY69lSmzkN2s0" 
                      //            "Maxhunter" => "this is my name" ]


Route::get('user', array('before' => 'old', function() {
  dd(Session::all()); // output 
                      // array:1 [▼"_token" => "gZ04sr3ymH0gclkcIY9bg0ZhowWj3lFkOnfW7a9v"]
```

Comment: after `Session::put()`, try `Session::save()`.

Comment: still same not saving

Answer (score 2):

For sessions to work properly, you must place your routes within the web middleware group.

In your `routes.php` file:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

    // Your routes go here

});
```